# Field fixed by a given aut group

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose I have an algebraic field extension $L/F$. What do I call the fixed field of $\operatorname{Aut}(L/F)$? It's sort of like the mirror image of the Galois closure: the smallest field $K>F$ such that $L/K$ is Galois.

As a particular example, what is the fixed field of $\operatorname{Aut}(\overline{F_p(t)}/F_p(t))$?

Comment: Call your group $G$, and then the field you want is $L^G$, I suppose. For your particular example, isn’t the answer $\Bbb F_p(t^{p^{-\infty}}$ ?

Comment: @lubin That sounds right. Since $L^{\operatorname{Aut}(\overline{F}/F)}$ is an invariant of any field $F$, I'm surprised it doesn't have a name, like the "blah closure".